# Redirect 301 multilanguage single domain to multistore with subdomains

Tags: redirect

Good afternoon,

I have the following structure on a multi-language website made with Prestashop with Apache server(I have access to htacces, Cpanel), is currently indexed in Google:

```
domain.es/es/
domain.es/pt/
domain.es/fr/
domain.es/de/
domain.es/en/
```

Now we want to go on to use Multistore to be able to have a better management in each country, therefore we want to create a subdomain for each country, in this aspect we know how to do it, but we are faced with the question of redirects of already indexed content.

We believe that the best way would be to use a domain.com with a subdomain of each country and dispense with the languages, leaving only the default language of each country, therefore we would eliminate /es/, /pt/, /fr/, etc.

Our domain.es/es/ is the one that is most positioned, would it be advisable to keep this and modify the other languages with domain.com? or is it indifferent and it would be better to structure everything with domain.con and its subdomains?

**Option 1:**

```
  domain.es/es/allpages  --redirect 301 to-->  domain.es/allpages
  domain.es/pt/allpages --redirect 301 to-->  pt.newdomain.com/allpages
  domain.es/de/allpages --redirect 301 to-->  de.newdomain.com/allpages 
  domain.es/fr/allpages --redirect 301 to-->  fr.newdomain.com/allpages  
  domain.es/en/allpages --redirect 301 to-->  eu.newdomain.com/allpages
```

**Option 2:**

```
  domain.es/es/allpages  --redirect 301 to-->  es.newdomain.com/allpages
  domain.es/pt/allpages --redirect 301 to-->  pt.newdomain.com/allpages
  domain.es/de/allpages --redirect 301 to-->  de.newdomain.com/allpages 
  domain.es/fr/allpages --redirect 301 to-->  fr.newdomain.com/allpages  
  domain.es/en/allpages --redirect 301 to-->  eu.newdomain.com/allpages
```

I tried this, is correct?

To set final urls like:

```
es.newdomain.com/
pt.newdomain.com/
de.newdomain.com/
fr.newdomain.com/
eu.newdomain.com/


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/es/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://es.newdomain.com/%1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pt/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://pt.newdomain.com/%1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fr/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://fr.newdomain.com/%1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/de/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://de.newdomain.com/%1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://eu.newdomain.com/%1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help, if we knew what webserver you are running. Based on the current information, the only thing, one could say, is that for instance `domain.es/pt/` supposedly should redirect to `pt.newdomain.com`. But I suppose you already know that ...

Comment: Are you using `Apache` server?

Comment: Hello @derpirscher we use an Apache server, it is an installation with Prestashop, I have access to edit the .htaccess file and Cpanel. I have redrafted the question so that you can understand my question better. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hello @AmitVerma we use an Apache server, it is an installation with Prestashop, I have access to edit the .htaccess file and Cpanel. I have redrafted the question so that you can understand my question better. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hi @jon-lin you could help me with this .htaccess issue?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65648668/redirect-301-multilanguage-single-domain-to-multistore-with-subdomains

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far? I would be happy to help you.

Comment: Hi @AmitVerma so far I have tried the following rules to add in .htaccess. Would they be correct?

Comment: Hi @AmitVermaI have added what I have tested in the upper text of the question. Thank you